# Photo stitching software

Tags: panorama

I have a series of photos captures with care to make up into a `panorama` photo. Can anyone suggest a good `software` which can stitch them in sequence without much manual intervention and providing good results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net). I have used this software to create panorama photos and it is pretty easy to use, even for a novice user.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind paying for software try Autopano Pro.
http://www.kolor.com/
There is a full working trial version, but it does watermark the result.
However one go with the trial was enough to convince me to purchase the Pro version.